# .htaccess from root directory prevents access to subdirectory php files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have a Magento installation in a root directory and a few standalone scripts in a subdirectory like this

```
app
index.php
...
.htaccess
scripts/
├── csv-generator
├── index.html
├── index.php
├── label-print
└── stock-manage
```

My problem is that whenver I try to access php or html files in /scripts directory the .htaccess from root directory seems to kick in and launches my magento application instead of the subdirectory scripts

docroot .htaccess

```
############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php7.ini

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

############################################
## php7 settings

<IfModule mod_php7.c>

############################################
## adjust max execution time

    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>

############################################
## Enable Developer Mode based on OS environment variable

    SetEnvIfExpr "osenv('MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE') == '1'" MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE=1

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>

        ############################################
        # X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

        ############################################
        # This header forces to enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter in browsers (if disabled)
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s8 ie8
        Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block" env=!ie8

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]


############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

        #AuthName "Cron auth"
        #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
        #AuthType basic
        #Require valid-user

############################################

        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all

    </Files>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Subdirectory .htaccess

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "Restricted area"
AuthUserFile "/home/passwd"
Require valid-user
```

It seems the   directive

`RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`

Is kicking in for all requests, and I'm trying to find a way to ignore the scripts directory so that it works normally. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put a `RewriteRule ^scripts/ - [END]` somewhere before that index.php rewrite.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Where did you put it, and what happens exactly?

Comment: I put it directly above the `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`
Website works fine but scripts directory turns back to the website's 404 page

Comment: What happens when you put it first? _"but scripts directory turns back to the website's 404 page"_ - when you request the directory itself, or a specific file in it?

Comment: I tried to put it write after `RewriteEngine on` just in case I was missing something, and the result is the same as before. Scripts directory and it's files return a 404 from the website which is located in the docroot

Answer (score 1):

> @CBroe: Put a `RewriteRule ^scripts/ - [END]` somewhere before that index.php rewrite.
>
> @OP: I put it directly above the `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`

---

> ```
> ############################################
> ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders
>
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
>
> ############################################
> ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
>
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>
>
> ############################################
> ## rewrite everything else to index.php
>
>     RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
> ```

This is one rule (it's just "confusingly" split up). You should not add another `RewriteRule` directive *immediatley* before the above `RewriteRule` directive as that will likely break your site. When it is stated to put something "before the index.php rewrite" it means *before* the entire rule, ie. before the first `RewriteCond` directive that applies to that rule.

However, in the above, you could just add `scripts` to the first `RewriteCond` directive.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js|scripts)/
```

This *condition* prevents the rule from being processed when any one of these root directories is requested.

However, ordinarily, the rule will naturally exclude requests for physical files and directories (that's what the 3 *conditions* in the middle are doing). However, for some reason this would not seem to be happening.

Comment: Indeed this is the first time I encounter this also that's why I asked. I tried your suggestion of adding the scripts path in the RewriteCond to exclude it, however nothing changes in the behavior. More specifically, I still get a 404 whether I try example.com/scripts/index.php or plain example.com/scripts in the URL 

Any idea what could be interfering or where to look at for further info?

Comment: @gabtzi When you initially put that rule "directly above the `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`" - was that literally just above that one directive? It's just that that should have broken magento. If it didn't then we need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I literally put it above this rule, and I also tried above on the very top. The result keeps staying the same no matter what I try. 

Commenting out this rule, Magento breaks, and scripts works.

Comment: Not really sure what is going on in that case?! Do you have any other `.htaccess` files, perhaps in the `/scripts` subdirectory? Are you behind a proxy/load balancer/CDN? It seems like when you request `/scripts/`, Apache is not seeing that? I would be interested to know what the value of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is at that point in the script? Or the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive? Since both are failing. (Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is not the same as the PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal.)

Comment: Scripts directory only had the basic auth .htaccess code nothing else. We're using cloudflare, but that doesn't seem to be the reason. Unfortunately I don't have full access to the VPS as it's a managed one so I wouldn't be able to get that information :( 

For now I asked the hosting provider to switch to litespeed and everything seems to work fine but it puzzled me so much to understand what was happening and I've been struggling for days with various .htaccess configuratons. 

It's as if the parent .htaccess is rewriting all similar options from the subdirectories